# Kafka 0.9: Durability and persistance of consumer offset vectors

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

If I understand correctly, the offsets are committed to the offset manager(broker) for the relevant topic and, I am assuming, sent to the zookeeper, but say, for example, I have a topic with a replication factor of 1 and the broker, who is the offset manager fails. Will I lose the committed offsets, since I am not replicating the servers? Will I only lose the offsets if my zookeeper server fails.

If not how does zookeeper/broker store the offsets to be recovered after server failure, and in what scenario, if any, would I lose the offsets?

Please let me know if I have an incorrect representation of the internals of kafka/zookeeper. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kafka 0.9.0 The offsets of the consumers are stores in a topic in kafka and replicated like the rest of the topics.